# Проблема с парсингом ссылки на PDF файл

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, ссылка

Всем привет, срочно нужна помощь! Python

Написал парсер и жду от него, что бы он мне пересылал ссылки с сайта на PDF документы, но при работе выдает None

```
from turtle import Turtle
from requests import request
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://kim-online.ru/page/navigatsiya/ezhesutochnaya-putevaya-informatsiya/ezhesutochnaya-putevaya-informatsiya-za-2022-god/4780-maj-2022"

page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

post = soup.find("div", class_="page-body")

url =post.find("p", class_="item-text marbot40", href=True)['href'].strip()

print(url)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
post = soup.find("div", class_="item-text marbot40")
# берем самый свежий 
url = post.find_all('a')[-1]['href']
print(f'https://kim-online.ru{url}')
```